# SQL unit value and cumulative sum by groups

Tags: sql

I'm still new to SQL and am kind of stumped on this one. I would greatly appreciate any help or advice. I have a table with a value column and an ID column that I then order by the value column in descending order. i.e:

```
Value   | ID   
12      | A  
09      | A  
08      | B  
08      | C  
07      | A  
06      | B  
03      | B  
01      | C
```

I am trying to do two things:

1. For each row, calculate the percent of the total sum for its respective ID. Row 1 would be 12/(12+9+7), row 2: 3/(12+9+7), row 3: 8/(8+6+3), etc.
2. Calculate the running total of the percentage calculated in (1) for each ID. Essentially just a cumulative sum for each ID.

The output would look something like this.

```
Value | ID | UnitValue | RunningTotal  
-------------------------------------
  12  | A  | 0.43      | 0.43  
  09  | A  | 0.32      | 0.75  
  08  | B  | 0.47      | 0.47  
  08  | C  | 0.89      | 0.89  
  07  | A  | 0.25      | 1.00  
  06  | B  | 0.35      | 0.82  
  03  | B  | 0.18      | 1.00  
  01  | C  | 0.11      | 1.00
```

Comment: Do you have SQL Server, MySQL, PostgreSQL? What version?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For SQL Server 2008

```
;WITH CTE 
AS
(
    SELECT
        Value
        ,ID
        ,CONVERT(DECIMAL(10,2),Value/CONVERT(DECIMAL(10,2),SUM(Value) OVER(PARTITION BY [ID]))) AS [Unit Value]
    FROM
        Table1 

)

SELECT a.Value,a.ID,a.[Unit Value], (SELECT SUM(b.[Unit Value])
               FROM   CTE b
               WHERE a.ID = b.ID AND b.[Unit Value] <= a.[Unit Value]) AS [RunningTotal]
FROM   CTE a
ORDER  BY a.ID,[RunningTotal]
```

[**SQL FIDDLE DEMO**](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!6/56366/3)

Answer (score 1):

Try to use 
over() partition by ()
statement

Answer (score 1):

In SQL Server 2012 or PostgreSQL you could use windowed functions, the query become fairly simple:

```
;with cte as (
  select
      Value, ID,
      cast(sum(Value) over(partition by ID) as decimal(29, 10)) as sum_id
  from Table1
)
select
    Value, ID,
    cast(Value / sum_id as decimal(29, 2)) as UnitValue, 
    cast(sum(Value / sum_id) over(partition by ID order by Value desc) as decimal(29, 2)) as RunningTotal
from cte
```

you can try it on [**sql fiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/b20b2/5) with example

Comment: I now see the value in using SQL Server 2012. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a fairly portable query that will obtain the first 3 columns. The running total may be achieved in various ways, including CTE on Microsoft SQL Server.

NOTE: The CASE block is to protect against a divide by zero error.

```
SELECT
    T.Value,
    T.ID,
    CASE
        WHEN SUMS.Total = 0 THEN 0.00
        ELSE (T.Value / SUMS.Total)
    END AS UnitValue
FROM
    MyTable T
    INNER JOIN
    (
    SELECT
        T1.ID,
        SUM(COALESCE(T1.Value, 1)) AS Total
    FROM
        MyTable T1
    GROUP BY
        T1.ID
    ) AS SUMS ON
        SUMS.ID = T.ID
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Oracle, you can make use of [RATIO_TO_REPORT](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e26088/functions142.htm#SQLRF00691) to calculate the ratio and [SUM](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e26088/functions182.htm#SQLRF06115) as analytical function to calculate the cumulative sum.

```
select value,
       id,
       r,
       sum(r) over (partition by id order by value desc) s
  from(
  select value,
         id,
         round(ratio_to_report(value) over (partition by id),2) r
    from mytable)
order by value desc;
```

`SUM` is available in other DBs, but not sure about `RATIO_TO_REPORT`.

Demo for Oracle [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/d41d8/15581).